# New construction window remove nail flange

Tags: windows

I received free metal new construction windows to use as replacement windows. Is this possible?  It will save on expenses for my project. If yes how do I remove the nail fin.

Comment: It's possible but you will have to remove siding. https://www.doityourself.com/forum/doors-skylights-windows/273138-how-do-i-remove-new-construction-vinyl-window.html#post1026356

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Unfortunately we can't answer with what you've provided. Please revise your question to provide relevant detail. As it is, any answers would be guesses. Do not post it in a comment.